# MySQL - Trigger UPDATE (How values change)

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I had a Trigger "*After Update*" in my table, but I need know how **column** changes.
I dont want do this:

```
IF OLD.*column* <> NEW.*column* THEN ...
```

Someone have a trick?

Comment: That's the only trick *I* know of...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No tricks. If you want to detect that the value of a column changed, you need to explicitly compare the values of `OLD.col` and `NEW.col`.

---

One quirk with SQL is the tri-valued boolean logic. And an inequality test to a NULL value will never return TRUE. (An expression evaluated in a boolean context can return one of three values: `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL`.

```
 foo  <> NULL    --> NULL
 NULL <> NULL    --> NULL
 foo  <> bar     --> TRUE
```

If you want to detect whether the value of a column was changed, including a change to or from a NULL value, the inequality test won't cut it.

One trick is to use the null-safe comparison operator (the spaceship symbol **`<=>`**) which will return only TRUE or FALSE, even when one or both of the values being compared are NULL, to detect a difference:

```
 IF NOT (NEW.col <=> OLD.col) THEN 
    -- value of col was modified
 END IF;
```

---

Another trick is to use a SQL statement to help generate some of the code you would need in the trigger body. Referencing the `columns` table in the `information_schema` database. This is a short example, but this could be extended to include additional statements, and the `END IF`. The return from this can be pasted into a text editor, to help you build the trigger body.

```
SELECT CONCAT(' IF NOT (NEW.`',c.column_name,'` <=> OLD.`',c.column_name,'`) THEN') AS i
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE c.table_name = 'mytable'
   AND c.table_schema = 'mydatabase'
 ORDER BY c.ordinal_position
```

returns something like

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
IF NOT (NEW.`id` <=> OLD.`id`) THEN
IF NOT (NEW.`created` <=> OLD.`created`) THEN
IF NOT (NEW.`display_name` <=> OLD.`display_name`) THEN
```

This can be very helpful if you have a lot of columns.

Aside from that, there aren't really any other "tricks".